# Weighting values based on variables

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statistics, scipy

I have a set of values that are basically answers to questions but when I count up the answers I want to pretend that I have a better distribution of responses by giving the answers weights.  Here is the code to show a simple example:

```
from pprint import pprint

q1 = [
    'blue',
    'orange',
    'red',
]

q2 = [
    'male',
    'female',
]

q3 = [
    '18-25',
    '26-30',
    '31-40',
    '41+'
]

data = [
    {'q1': 1, 'q2': 1, 'q3': 0},  # orange, female, 18-25
    {'q1': 0, 'q2': 1, 'q3': 0},  # blue, female, 18-25
    {'q1': 1, 'q2': 0, 'q3': 0},  # orange, male, 18-25
    {'q1': 2, 'q2': 1, 'q3': 1},  # red, female, 26-30
    {'q1': 2, 'q2': 1, 'q3': 1},  # red, female, 26-30
    {'q1': 1, 'q2': 0, 'q3': 1},  # orange, male, 18-25
]

counts = {
    'q1': {},
    'q2': {},
    'q3': {}
}

respondent_value = 1

for respondent in data:
    q1_val = q1[respondent['q1']]
    q2_val = q2[respondent['q2']]
    q3_val = q3[respondent['q3']]

    if q1_val not in counts['q1']:
        counts['q1'][q1_val] = 0

    counts['q1'][q1_val] += respondent_value

    if q2_val not in counts['q2']:
        counts['q2'][q2_val] = 0

    counts['q2'][q2_val] += 1

    if q3_val not in counts['q3']:
        counts['q3'][q3_val] = 0

    counts['q3'][q3_val] += respondent_value

pprint(counts)
```

This currently will print the following values:

```
{'q1': {'blue': 1, 'orange': 3, 'red': 2},
 'q2': {'female': 4, 'male': 2},
 'q3': {'18-25': 3, '26-30': 3}}
```

I would like to instead pretend that I have the following demographics:

- 50% male
- 50% female
- 40% 18-15
- 60% 26-30

How would automatically generate weights for this data given what I want to represent?  For given values that don't match a demographic I'll just assume a weight of 1.

I'm interested in using pandas/numpy if they are helpful but will use whatever tool works best.

For single value weighting I would probably do it like this (I need multiple variables):

```
from pprint import pprint

q1 = [
    'blue',
    'orange',
    'red',
]

q2 = [
    'male',
    'female',
]

q3 = [
    '18-25',
    '26-30',
    '31-40',
    '41+'
]

data = [
    {'q1': 1, 'q2': 1, 'q3': 0},  # orange, female, 18-25
    {'q1': 0, 'q2': 1, 'q3': 0},  # blue, female, 18-25
    {'q1': 1, 'q2': 0, 'q3': 0},  # orange, male, 18-25
    {'q1': 2, 'q2': 1, 'q3': 1},  # red, female, 26-30
    {'q1': 2, 'q2': 1, 'q3': 1},  # red, female, 26-30
    {'q1': 1, 'q2': 0, 'q3': 1},  # orange, male, 18-25
]


def get_counts(male_weight, female_weight):
    counts = {
        'q1': {},
        'q2': {},
        'q3': {}
    }

    for respondent in data:
        q1_val = q1[respondent['q1']]
        q2_val = q2[respondent['q2']]
        q3_val = q3[respondent['q3']]

        if q2_val == 'female':
            respondent_value = female_weight
        else:
            respondent_value = male_weight

        if q1_val not in counts['q1']:
            counts['q1'][q1_val] = 0

        counts['q1'][q1_val] += respondent_value

        if q2_val not in counts['q2']:
            counts['q2'][q2_val] = 0

        counts['q2'][q2_val] += respondent_value

        if q3_val not in counts['q3']:
            counts['q3'][q3_val] = 0

        counts['q3'][q3_val] += respondent_value

    return counts

total_respondents = len(data) * 1.0
counts = get_counts(1, 1)
print("Starting counts")
print("=================")
pprint(counts)
print("\n")

female_pop = 50
male_pop = 50

sample_females = (counts['q2']['female'] / total_respondents) * 100
sample_males = (counts['q2']['male'] / total_respondents) * 100

female_weight = female_pop / sample_females
male_weight = male_pop / sample_males

weighted_counts = get_counts(male_weight, female_weight)
print("Weighted Counts")
print("===============")
pprint(weighted_counts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a distribution of the responses for color, but you want to give more weight to the under-represented age and gender groups in your sample. For example, if twice as many women responded as men, you want to give the men's answers twice the weight. If that's correct, here is an approach with pandas:

```
In [70]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(color=["orange","blue","orange","red","red","orange"],gender=["female","female","male","female","female","male"], age=["18-25", "18-25", "18-25", "26-30", "26-30", "18-25"]))

In [71]: gender_dist = pd.Series([.5,.5], index=["female","male"])

In [72]: age_dist = pd.Series([.4,.6], index=["18-25","26-30"])
```

Calculate the weights you'll need to apply to achieve your target age/gender distribution:

```
In [73]: gender_weights = gender_dist / df.gender.groupby(df.gender).count()

In [74]: age_weights = age_dist / df.age.groupby(df.age).count()

In [75]: age_weights
Out[75]: 
18-25    0.1
26-30    0.3
dtype: float64
```

Pivot the sample data to get counts of each color, by age and gender:

```
In [76]: df["value"] = 1

In [77]: pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df, values="value", columns="color", index=["gender","age"], aggfunc="count", fill_value=0)

In [78]: pivoted
Out[78]: 
color         blue  orange  red
gender age                     
female 18-25     1       1    0
       26-30     0       0    2
male   18-25     0       2    0
```

Reindex your weights to align with the pivot table index:

```
In [79]: index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([gender_weights.index, age_weights.index], names=["gender","age"])

In [80]: gender_weights = gender_weights.reindex(index, level=0)

In [81]: age_weights = age_weights.reindex(index, level=1)

In [82]: age_weights
Out[82]: 
gender  age  
female  18-25    0.1
        26-30    0.3
male    18-25    0.1
        26-30    0.3
dtype: float64
```

Multiply by the weights:

```
In [83]: weighted_counts = pivoted.mul(age_weights, axis=0).mul(gender_weights, axis=0)

In [84]: weighted_counts
Out[84]: 
color           blue  orange    red
gender age                         
female 18-25  0.0125  0.0125  0.000
       26-30  0.0000  0.0000  0.075
male   18-25  0.0000  0.0500  0.000
       26-30     NaN     NaN    NaN
```

Get the weighted distribution, then normalize it:

```
In [85]: dist = weighted.sum()

In [86]: dist / dist.sum()
Out[86]: 
color
blue      0.083333
orange    0.416667
red       0.500000
dtype: float64
```